# Prove $f'(t)\leq0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $u: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. We define $f(t)=u(\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

Given that for every $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ the following is true: $$y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\geq0$$

Prove that $f'(t)\leq0$ for every $t$ in $[0,2\pi]$.

**What I did until now?**

I have calculated
$$
f'(t) = \cos(t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\sin(t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$
According to what is given, I get that $f'(t)\leq0$ for every $t$ and not only for $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: any hint to where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$f'(t) = \frac {\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{d(\cos t)}{dt} + \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}\frac {d(\sin t)}{dt} = \frac {\partial u}{\partial x} (-\sin t) + \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}\cos t = -y\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + x\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$

and by our given condition $-y\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + x\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} \le 0$

$f'(t)\le 0$  for all $t.$

Since $f(t)$ is periodic.  It seems to me that this condition would imply that
$f$ is either constant or discontinuous.

Comment: So I was right and it's for every t. Plus how could I prove that it is constant?

Comment: I am given that partial derivatives are continuous